Local Notifications not getting triggered in IOS when app is running on background
Hello I have this function which I am calling from DispatchSourceTimer when the app is in background and the timer is running for every  5 mins
private func scheduleNotification() {
    NotificationManager.shared.removeAllPendingNotifications()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "######"
    content.body = "##### "
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {

            print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

And The local Notification is not getting triggered sometimes. Can anyone please help with this issue .Is this expected or do I need to modify the qos level or anything.Any advice would be appreciated
I Have tried to dispatch from a global queue and increased the trigger Time but still no use

You said,

I am calling from DispatchSourceTimer when App is in background and the timer is running for every 5 mins

Are you 100% sure the app is actually is running in the background and not suspended?
Generally background execution is limited to a very narrow set of use-cases (navigation apps, VOIP apps, etc.) and generally when you leave the app, it goes into background only momentarily and then is quickly suspended.
In general, you cannot have an app run a repeating timer in the background perpetually. As a developer, this is a little annoying, but as a iOS user this is great, because if all of our apps could continually run in the background, our batteries would be quickly exhausted.
By the way, if you really want a notification every five minutes, you might set the repeats parameter to true, e.g.:
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 300, repeats: true)

That way, the app does not need to be running in the background. And you do not need a timer.

Is this expected…

Yes.

… or do I need to modify the qos level or anything … I have tried to dispatch from a global queue…

Nope, it is not a question of how your dispatch source timer was configured. The issue is that execution while an app is in a “background” state is not permitted except for very specific use-cases.
Please do not conflate a “background” app state and a “background” dispatch queue. They are two completely different and unrelated concepts. One references an app state and the other references the priority (and thread) used by a dispatch queue.

By the way, do not test this behavior while attached to the Xcode debugger (as that artificially keeps an app running in the background), but rather quit Xcode and launch it directly from the device. And, when testing an app directly on the device, because you are not going to be attached to the Xcode debugger, you will not be able to see your print statements, so you might consider using Logger, instead:
import os.log

let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "Notifications")

private func scheduleNotification() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "######"
    content.body = "##### "
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error {
            logger.error("\(#function, privacy: .public): Error scheduling notification: \(error, privacy: .public)")
        }
    }
}

If you follow this pattern with all of your error messages, you can then monitor progress real-time from the macOS Console app. Or, alternatively, you can download the logs from your device and then open this logarchive (which will launch the Console app):
$ log collect --device --start '2024-05-29 08:00:00' —output Foo.logarchive
$ open Foo.logarchive

Note, these logs can be huge, especially when you start filtering the results for your particular bundle identifier, so try to keep the time period specified by the --start option to something short as possible.
